# How can I force achart engine to stop resizing charts?

Tags: android, mobile, charts, achartengine

I am using achart engine v1.1.0 to paint some graphics in a scrollview in my app.
The problem is that on small screens the when I scroll down the graphics auto resize and end up badly placed or sometimes they even disappear. which makes for a pretty lousy user experience.

Is this a known issue, is there anyway around it?
(sorry about the censored texts)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to try is:

```
renderer.setInScroll(true);
```

This usually helps when the chart is embedded in a scroll or other UI component.